# How to remove subsection extra spacing

Tags: pdftex

I have this extra space appearing between the text and the subsection. Not sure how to remove it. It happens just in this spot.

[image]

---

PS: I just noticed that when using these macros I created in one of the pictures captions that precedes this section, the gap in question is increased.

```
\renewcommand{\suggestadd}[1]{%
\textcolor{Green}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\suggestremove}[1]{%
\textcolor{red}{\st{#1}}%
}
```

Comment: Never just show an image, show code so others can see what you are doing and test your code

Comment: Thanks, I will do it ASAP.

Comment: presumably you are using `\flushbottom` and the item at the top of the next break is something unbreakable that would not fit on the current page, so this page has to be stretched to achieve the specified position for the final baseline.

Comment: I am not using `\flushbottom`, also, if the text preceding this subsection is too large, it extra gap does not appear.